# Not rejecting H0(Null Hypothesis) when H0 is False is Type 2 error?

Tags: logic, hypothesis-testing

Why failing to reject a null hypothesis $H_0$ is type 2 false negative?

In my understanding:

1. **False Positive (Type 1)** is judging a false statement **incorrectly as true**.
2. **False Negative (Type 2)** is judging a true statement **incorrectly as false**.

Suppose a medicine Y is effective but X is placebo that has no effect. The null hypothesis $H_0$ will be `(Y is X)` meaning Y is as ineffective as placebo, and **$H_0$ is a false statement**.

Then, judging $H_0$ **incorrectly as true** should be type 1 false positive. However, it is false negative.

- [Type II error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_II_error)

> The second kind of error is the mistaken failure to reject the null hypothesis as the result of a test procedure. This sort of error is called a type II error (false negative)

Why is judging the alternative hypothesis $H_a$, which is a true statement `(Y is NOT X)`, as false not type 2 false negative?

Please help understand why.

Comment: There are several issues with this, the biggest being what one concludes from hypothesis testing. Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.